# Alguien me podia explicar esta funcion?

Tags: javascript

Mi maestra nos dejo una activdad con este codigo, pero no entiendo muy bien como funciona, alguien me podria explicar por favor?
arreglo=[1,3,4,3,4,5,5,5]

```
function moda(arr){
    return orden.sort((a,b) => 
                       orden.filter(v => v===a).length 
                       - orden.filter(v => v===b).length
                      ).pop();
}
console.log(moda(arreglo));
```

Comment: Comienza por revisar [*Funciones Flecha*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que veo la función `moda()` tiene un error pues hace uso de una variable llamada **orden** la cual no está definida.

Propongo esta corrección

```
arreglo=[1,3,4,3,4,5,5,5];
function moda(arr){
    return arr.sort((a,b) => 
        arr.filter(v => v===a).length 
        - arr.filter(v => v===b).length
    ).pop();
}
console.log(moda(arreglo));
```

---

### Método `pop()`

El método `pop()` elimina el último elemento de un array y lo devuelve. Este método cambia la longitud del array.

```js
arreglo=[1,3,4,5];
console.log(arreglo.pop());
console.log(arreglo);
```

> 5
> [1,3,4]

---

### Método `.filter()`

El método filter() crea un nuevo array con todos los elementos que cumplan la condición implementada por la función dada.

```js
arreglo=[1,3,4,3,4,5,5,5]
let res = arreglo.filter(v => v===3)
console.log(res);
```

> [3,3];

La forma en la que está declarada la función se conoce como ***función flecha***

```js
//Función declarada
comparar(v){
    return v === 3
}
let res = arreglo.filter(comparar);

//Función anónima
let res = arreglo.filter(function (v){ 
              return v === 3
          });

//Función flecha
let res = arreglo.filter(v => v===3);
```

---

## Método `sort()`

### Sintaxis

```js
arr.sort([compareFunction])
```

### Descripción

El método sort ordena los elementos de una arreglo localmente y devuelve el arreglo ya ordenado.
El parámetro `compareFunction` es opcional; si se especifica, esta define el método de ordenamiento. Si se omite, el array es ordenado atendiendo a la posición del valor **Unicode** de cada carácter, según la conversión a string de cada elemento.

### Parámetro `compareFunction`

Cuando se provee este parámetro, los elementos arrays son ordenados de acuerdo al valor que retorna la función al comparar los elementos. Siendo `a` y `b` los elementos a comparar:

- Si el valor que retorna `compareFunction(a,b)` es menor que cero, quiere decir que `a` va primero que `b` según el criterio de ordenamiento.
- Si el valor que retorna `compareFunction(a,b)` es igual a cero, se deja `y` y `b` sin cambios entre ellos, pero ordenados con respecto a todos los elementos diferentes.
- Si el valor que retorna `compareFunctions(a,b)` es mayor a cero, quiere decir que `b` va primero que `a` según el criterio de ordenamiento.

> **Nota**
> `a` toma el valor de la posición 1 del arreglo; mientras que `b` toma el valor de la posición 0 del arreglo

---

## Función `moda(arr)`

La función `moda()`, somo su nombre lo indica, busca devolver el valor que más se repite dentro de un array que toma como parámetro.
Primero usa el método `sort()` dándole como parámetro la función que establece el criterio de ordenamiento

```js
function moda(arr){
    return arr.sort((a,b) => 
        arr.filter(v => v===a).length 
        - arr.filter(v => v===b).length
    );
}
```

En el criterio de ordenamiento vemos que hace uso del método `filter()`

```js
arr.filter(v => v===a).length - arr.filter(v => v===b).length
```

Con éste obtiene dos arreglos, uno lleno de elementos `a` y otro de elementos `b`. Luego obtiene el largo de estos arreglos y resta el de `a`.contra el de `b`.
De esta forma, los elementos que tienen más concurrencia los va desplazando hacia el final del arreglo.

Al final, con el método `pop()` obtiene el elemento de la última posición del arreglo que, por la forma en que se acomodan los datos con el criterio de ordenamiento, debe de ser el elemento que más se repite en el arreglo.

```
function moda(arr){
    return arr.sort(...).pop();
}
```

---

Como nota adicional. No hay forma de determinar si otro elemento se repite igual numero de veces con esta forma de ordenamiento ya que tomará el último elemento en el arreglo.
Esto lo puede comprobar con estos arreglos:
arreglo=[3,3,3,5,5,5,4,1];
arreglo=[5,5,5,3,3,3,4,1];
Si quieres ver como quedan ordenados los arreglos, quita el método `pop()`.

Comment: Por un momento me sentí en un curso gratuito avanzado

Comment: La verdad yo tambien, esta demasiado completa la información, muchas gracias:3